# Is there a way to adjust buffer size in VLC-Qt (example set to 50ms)?

Tags: qt, media-player, vlc-qt

I am currently playing around with a network camera and am getting the rtsp video stream using VLC-QT on Qt Creator, however, the streaming buffer is so large there is ~ 2-3 second delay.

Is there a way to adjust the buffer setting (example : set to 50ms ). For live video streaming

Anybody run into this and try to change the buffer setting? On Windows Qt Creator

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the network cache in libvlc did the trick for me:

```cpp
QStringList args = VlcCommon::args();
args << "--network-caching=200";
VlcInstance *instance = new VlcInstance(args, this);
```

I couldn't go as low as 50ms though.